# Git - Alterar mensagem de commits

Tags: git, github

Como faço para alterar a mensagem que fiz em um determinado commit?

Exemplo:

```
Primeira Mensagem             1212121
Segunda Mensagem              8989898
```

Já tentei com:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
git commit --force
```

mas não deu certo... Não da erro mas também não atualiza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, sugiro que leia o tutorial do próprio Git disponibilizado [aqui](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Reescrevendo-o-Hist%C3%B3rico).

Mas basicamente, você irá fazer o comando `git rebase -i HEAD~2` da mesma maneira que está fazendo atualmente, indicando que deseja fazer um rebase iterativo. Após isso, irá ser mostrada uma mensagem contendo os commits e algumas opções, entre elas a opção `r, reword` que corresponde a utilizar o mesmo commit, mas reescrever sua mensagem.

Você irá então entrar no modo de edição no terminal e substituir `pick` que precede o hash do commit por `r`.  Após isso, você sai do modo de edição, salva e continua. Então serão mostrados os commits que você deseja alterar a mensagem, você altera as mensagens entrando no modo de edição e, após alterar, salva e continua. Finalmente você efetua o comando `git commit --amend`. Pronto, você alterou as mensagens de commit.